# how to force upgrade of coreutils on old distribution?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm running an oldish kubuntu
"precise"

I need a more up to date version of basename with the -s option. Can I force this somehow?

Seems I need 8.14 looking at a version I see on a newer box.

Comment: Do you need an updated version of `basename` for an specific use or system wide?

Comment: Either way really. whatever is quickest just to get this thing working!

Comment: I've actually built coreutils 8.21 from source and copied the new basename into /usr/local/bin as a workaround. But I would like to know if there is a "proper" way to get apt to do this for me!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/335583/how-do-i-selectively-install-a-package-from-a-ppa?lq=1 - the OP mentions a PPA that you might find useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The “proper” way to install newer software would be to upgrade your distribution. That's the principle of a released distribution: take a specific version of many pieces of software, test them operating together, and release the lot.

Ubuntu sometimes provides newer software for older but still supported distributions, in the form of [backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports). But there's no backport of coreutils for precise.

You can compile a newer package from source and install it, either by building the Ubuntu source package and using `dpkg` to install the resulting deb, or by compiling the upstream source and installing them under `/usr/local`. But beware that sometimes a newer version of a package — especially such a fundamental package as coreutils — can break things.

If it's only a specific program that requires a newer version of coreutils, install a newer version in a specific directory (like `/usr/local/other/coreutils-8.21`) and add `/usr/local/other/coreutils-8.21/bin` to the PATH only when running that specific program, with a wrapper script like

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/other/coreutils-8.21/bin:$PATH
exec that-specific-program "$@"
```

Do you really need a newer version of coreutils? `basename -s SUFFIX FILENAME` can also be written `basename FILENAME SUFFIX` which works with older versions.

Comment: Thanks, in the end we went exactly with the basename FILENAME SUFFIX option, much easier, thanks!